# How do I find and replace a part of a string variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am working with a variable which is basically URLs. So observations include values like for example

- `www.google.com`
- `https://www.google.com`
- `https://yahoo.movies.com`

I am trying to create a do file to import a bunch of these files into Stata and need a reliable method to remove the `www.` and the `https://` parts from these variables over a wide range of URLs.

In Excel I can do this simply by finding `https://` or `www.` and replacing it with nothing, how do I achieve the same in Stata?

I am working in Stata 13.1 SE on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`subinstr()`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?subinstr%28%29) function.

Example:

```
subinstr("this is this","is","X",.) = "thX X thX"
```